# enable exec on CentOS via shell

Tags: centos, centos6

I am trying to install a script, and managed to get all warnings cleared, except of this one:

```
    Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in XXXXXXXXX
```

This is a VPS, so I have full SSH access.

It is not disabled within the php.ini filed, nor is the safe_mode activated.

Answer (score 0):

there are two places where this function could be disabled

first locate your php.ini file and search for `disable_functions =`

remove `exec` from that list

also whilst yr in that file make sure `safe_mode` is not set to on

next, it could be disabled per virtual host in apache

look in your virtual hosts if there is this line under the domain in question `suhosin.executor.func.blacklist=` then remove `exec` if its in that list

example where a hosts file is located for apache running zpanel

/etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf